# Import data from ebay to google spreadsheet using IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to Import a table from "https://www.ebay.com/itm/100-NEW-ALTERNATOR-VW-GOLF-GTI-GL-GLS-1-8T-1-8-2L-99-06-90A-1-YR-WARRANTY-13852/301364941754?fits=Model%3AJetta&hash=item462ac013ba:g:v7oAAOSw~YRagU4N&vxp=mtr" to a Google Spread sheet using =IMPORTXML function, The Formula I was using as below,

A1 = https://www.ebay.com/itm/100-NEW-ALTERNATOR-VW-GOLF-GTI-GL-GLS-1-8T-1-8-2L-99-06-90A-1-YR-WARRANTY-13852/301364941754?fits=Model%3AJetta&hash=item462ac013ba:g:v7oAAOSw~YRagU4N&vxp=mtr

A2 = //*[@id="w1-20ctbl"]

A3 = =IMPORTXML(A1,A2)

But it returns nothing and It says "Imported content is empty."

Can Somebody help me, I'm new to google sheet scripting and I'll really grateful if somebody can help me.

waiting to hearing from somebody....

Thanks

Comment: There is no element on that page with the id "w1-20ctbl"

Comment: Thanks @Diego, Can you please tell me how to get the Xpath to that table. There is only one table in that Url page

Comment: I don't know what table you're referring to

Comment: @Diego, There is one table in that page, table headings are Notes,Year Make,Model,Trim Engine

Comment: I took the Xpath inspecting the web page on google crome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the pictured table using `IMPORTXML` or any built-in Google Sheets formula because the table is generated when a user visits the website.

[image]

If you look at the [page source](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm), you'll see that the table does not exist. `IMPORTPATH` looks at this page source, which is the content *before* javascript rendering by the browser. When you "inspect" an element in your browser, it's inspecting the content *after* the javascript has been rendered.

Unfortunately, there is not a simple way to get the data you're looking for. You'll have to find or build your own scraping tool. Be careful not to violate eBay terms of use or any local laws.

Comment: Thank you very much @Diego, just a small thing, can I use "UrlFetchApp.fetch" to do this, I mean in Script

Comment: @user9614426 You can certainly try! Should be relatively easy to check. After you get the HTML content using `UrlFetch`, just search for "w1-20ctbl".

Comment: this is the code I am using now for doing this, am I doing something wrong,

Comment: function update_leaderboard(){
  var url = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/100-NEW-ALTERNATOR-VW-GOLF-GTI-GL-GLS-1-8T-1-8-2L-99-06-90A-1-YR-WARRANTY-13852/301364941754?fits=Model%3AJetta&hash=item462ac013ba:g:v7oAAOSw~YRagU4N&vxp=mtr"
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var response = result.getContentText();
  //var data = JsonL.parse(response);
  var w = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = w.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(result);
  //Write the JSON to the spreadsheet...
}

Comment: @user9614426 I just tried it and doesn't seem like that will work.

Comment: thank you for the support, If you found way in future kindly let me know.